# how to run same jquerycode for different blocks in on html content?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am going to make a jQuery code for two different blocks, that works on one query code using drag and drop shoppinng cart element.

Here is my  js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/GMC7B/2/

In this exercise you can see that there are two different blocks: `post1` and `post2`. When I am dragging `post1` at his position, the `post2` position also display it automatically.

I want to run it using one common shopping cart. Please help me to sort out. There is my problem image http://screencast.com/t/oqywpdobF2vq

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant code; don't just "link" to a fiddle, especially when your "link" isn't even clickable.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a single .droppable() , you will have to use droppable() separately for each div

Comment: nouphal @if i pick post1 then right now both block are blink but i want restriction  that one block that i picked up it has to blink which related to it and vice versa

Comment: is this what you need? see dragging post1 http://jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/2/ . if yes please confirm

Comment: nouphal @Actually my question is like this i want to make my code modular so i want to make one function for the all shopping cart  my latest fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/6/ in this you can see that there is four post in which the post1 and post3 have same class and it and post 2 and post4 have same id and class bt they have different parent class so i want that if i pick up post3 then post1 shopping cart should not be blink and if i pick post1 then post3 shopping cart shoul not be blink and same thing for post2 and post4

Comment: $(".shoppingCart ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept:'.credit1',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
         test.call(this,event, ui);
        
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
}); i want to modular this code which select shopping cart as per parent id or class

Comment: Is your `html` format is correct? It seems incorrect because `class="newDiv"` has another `class="newDiv"` inside it.

Comment: here is now correct fiddle you can check this have diffrent parent  div element http://jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/9/

Comment: your little information bro in this case i have two exrcise jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/10 jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/11 and i have common js file for above two exrcise and i am going to run this exrcise on one html page that is seems like this fiddle jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/9 so how can i run this two ercise in one page and my real problem is in this image screencast.com/t/Vimi7Zjb2lkc i dont want to blink and accept the value which are not related to element hope you will help me soon –

Answer (score 0):

this `$(".shoppingCart ol").droppable(/*anything*/);` means that you are doing ALL `.shoppingCart ol` lists available for drop - **at ANY time** when something is dragged

Possible solution:

Prepare your dropable for all lists - and than use `disable()` method to turn them off

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable( "disable" );
```

When you start to drag some element - add "onDrag" function/method which will enable for drop

`$( ".selector" ).droppable( "enable" );`

only the elements you desire - also it should contain "onDrop" function/method which will disable droppable area again.

Comment: i didnt got your point can you help me to improvr my jsfiddle?

Comment: your little information bro in this case i have two exrcise jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/10 jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/11 and i have common js file for above two exrcise and i am going to run this exrcise on one html page that is seems like this fiddle jsfiddle.net/Er2Ef/9 so how can i run this two ercise in one page and my real problem is in this image screencast.com/t/Vimi7Zjb2lkc i dont want to blink and accept the value which are not related to element hope you will help me soon